# How to stop the looping for my code after the password is correct for c programing

Tags: c, for-loop, return, break

The looping does not stop after the password is entered correctly - why is it happening?

The password is `1234`, but after it has been entered, the looping couldn't stop, and it will loop. After 5 times loop will stop, and it can't use break or anything.

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <stdlib.h>
   
int check_pass(int pass);

int main()
{
    int x,pass;

    for(x=0;x<5;x++){ //the looping couldn't stop
    printf("Enter your password: ");
    scanf("%d",&pass);
    check_pass(pass);
    }
    return 0;
}

int check_pass(int pass)
{
    if(pass == 1234){
        printf("Password is correct\n");
        printf("==============  Hospital City  =============== ");
    }
    else{
        printf("Password is wrong, please try again\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Give a proper return value in `check_pass` and use `break`.

Comment: scanning password as integer is going to give you lots of sleepless nights.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Could you please mention what are some potential drawbacks of that approach?

Answer (score 0):

You need better replace your `for` loop with a `while` loop with a condition:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
    
bool check_pass(int pass);
    
int main()
    
{
  int x,pass;
  bool Continue = true;

  x = 0;

  while (Continue && (x < 5))
  {
    printf("Enter your password: ");
    scanf("%d",&pass);
    if (check_pass(pass))
    {
      printf("Password is correct\n");
      printf("==============  Hospital City  =============== ");
      Continue = false;
    }
    else
    {
      printf("Password is wrong, please try again\n");
      x++;
    }    
  }
  
  return 0;
}
bool check_pass(int pass)
{
  bool Result;
  
  if(pass == 1234){
    Result = true;
  }
  else {
    Result = false;
  }

  return Result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Devolus has mentioned in a comment, a solution with minimal changes would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <stdlib.h>
        
int check_pass(int pass);
        
int main()   
{
    int x, pass;
        
    for(x=0;x<5;x++) { //the looping couldn't stop
        printf("Enter your password: ");
        scanf("%d",&pass);
        if (check_pass(pass)) {
            break;
        }
    }
        
    return 0;
}

int check_pass(int pass)
{
    if(pass == 1234) {
        printf("Password is correct\n");
        printf("==============  Hospital City  =============== ");
        return 1;
    } else {
        printf("Password is wrong, please try again\n");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change needed is commented in the following code-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int check_pass(int pass);

int main()
{
    int x,pass;

    for(x=0;x<5;x++){
        printf("Enter your password: ");
        scanf("%d",&pass);
        if( check_pass(pass) == 1){// change in code
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;

}
int check_pass(int pass)
{
    if(pass == 1234){
        printf("Password is correct\n");
        printf("==============  Hospital City  =============== ");
        return 1;// change in code
    }
    else{
        printf("Password is wrong, please try again\n");
        return 0;// change in code
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you must always control the return value of `scanf`. If you do not and get a non digit value, every following `scanf` will choke on that character, and leave it in the input buffer for the next one => infinite loop.

Next, if you decide to test a validity in a function (which is good), the function must return a different value for a valid and invalid test, and that returned value must be checked in the caller.

Code could become:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int check_pass(int pass);

int main()

{
    int x, pass, cr;

    for (x=0; x<5; x++) { //allow 5 tries
        printf("Enter your password: ");
        cr = scanf("%d", &pass);       // ensure an integer was given
        if (cr != 1) {
            char buf[1024];           // "flush" input line in not
            if (NULL == fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin)) {
                printf("Read error");  // give up on EOF or error
                break;
            }
            continue;                // do not test validity here
        }
        cr = check_pass(pass);       // test the integer value
        if (1 == cr) break;          // break loop if correct
    }
    return 1 - cr;                   // return 0 only on a correct password

}
int check_pass(int pass)
{
    if (pass == 1234) {
        printf("Password is correct\n");
        printf("==============  Hospital City  =============== ");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Password is wrong, please try again\n");
    return 0;
}
```